# In a dataframe group rows containing a list over one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe (df) (All columns contain lists, except type, contains strings)

```
Type    Components        names
Zebra  [hand,arm,nose]   [bubu,kuku]
Zebra   [eyes,fingers]   [gaga,timber]
Zebra   [paws]           []
Lion    [teeth]          [scar]
Tiger   [fingers]        [figgy]
```

I want to group them based on Type so the output is like this:

```
Type    Components                           Names
Zebra   [hand,arm,nose,eyes,fingers,paws]    [bubu,kuku,gaga,timber]
Lion    [teeth]                              [scar]
Tiger   [fingers]                            [figgy]
```

I tried things like:

```
df.groupby('role')
```

I wasn't successful with using .agg in the end also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
`groupby` + `sum`
Not optimised, does not account for duplicates

```
df.groupby('Type', sort=False, as_index=False).sum()

    Type                              Components                       names
0  Zebra  [hand, arm, nose, eyes, fingers, paws]  [bubu, kuku, gaga, timber]
1   Lion                                 [teeth]                      [scar]
2  Tiger                               [fingers]                     [figgy]
```

---

**Option 2**
`groupby` + `agg` + `itertools.chain`
Accounts for duplicate, and very efficient with flattening

```
from itertools import chain
df.groupby('Type', sort=False, as_index=False).agg(
    lambda x: list(set(chain.from_iterable(x)))
)

    Type                              Components                       names
0  Zebra  [eyes, hand, paws, arm, fingers, nose]  [timber, bubu, gaga, kuku]
1   Lion                                 [teeth]                      [scar]
2  Tiger                               [fingers]                     [figgy]
```